# How to refresh jquery news ticker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js which will show a news ticker in my jsp page.
How will I update it? I tried inserting an setTimeout, but every time it refreshes it creates a new news ticker.. 
My code..

```
$('document').ready(function init(){

var url =     "http://localhost:8080/RestartSpringRestService/rest/getAllSiteLatestCriticalParams";
var i = 1;
$.getJSON(url, function(data){

       $.each(data, function(i, item) {  
               alert("hiii::"+":::::::"+item.bufferCount+":::::::"+item.cpu+":::::::"+item.memory);
              $("#news ul").append("").append("").append("").append("").liScroll();
              i++;
        });
//           refresh ticker
       setTimeout(init,1000);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It creates a new element because you are using `append`.
If you want to update the page you should use functions like `.html("your code here")` or similar.

Comment: `.html()` is also doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is S M Hasibu Islam, working web development field from 2009 to till now. If you don’t know how to create a jQuery news ticker, in bellows tutorial I’ll teach you how to create a news ticker using HTML, CSS & jQuery.

**Step: 1**

I have written basic code and include necessary files for getting view of news ticker.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My jQuery News Ticker</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js "></script>
    </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Step: 2**

The second step is to add the HTML code.

```
<div class=“csehasibticker”>
   <h3>Breaking News</h3>
   <ul id=“csehasibticker”>
       <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry...</li>
       <li>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</li>
<ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available...</li>
</ul>
<ul>
       <li>All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Step: 3**

Our HTML code is included into our main HTML code.

```
<!-- Include jQuery function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function csehasibticker() {
            jQuery('#csehasibticker li:first').slideUp(function() {
               jQuery(this).appendTo($('#csehasibticker')).slideDown();
            });
        }
       setInterval(csehasibticker, 4000);
    </script>
<!-- //Include jQuery function -->
```

**Step: 4** 
Finally we add our CSS inside the head tag or just above the body tag.

```
<style>
            #wrapper{
            width:80%;
            margin:0 auto;
            }
            .csehasibticker{
            width: 550px;
            height: 255px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #eee;
            background:  #00a1e0;
            color:#fff;
            text-align: left;
            margin:0 auto;
            }
            .csehasibticker h3 {
            padding: 0 0 7px 7px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
            }
            ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-style: italic;
            }
            ul li {
            list-style: none;
            height:50px;
            padding:7px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
            }
        </style>
```

Finally, we have created the news ticker & tested online. Please see full source code of **[How to Create News Ticker Using HTML CSS and jQuery](http://www.e2softsolution.com/create-news-ticker-using-html-css-jquery/)**